# Why does this python ffmpeg module output h.264 instead of h.265 when downloading a video?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, download, encode

I'm trying to use [this](https://pypi.org/project/python-ffmpeg-video-streaming/) python module to download a video and transcode it to h.265

For some reason whenever I run my script it outputs h.264, no matter which format I specify.

Here is my code:

```py
import ffmpeg_streaming as ffmpeg

video = ffmpeg.input(vid_url)
stream = video.stream2file(ffmpeg.Formats.hevc())
stream.output('test.mp4')
```

This should output 'test.mp4' encoded using h.265, however it is always h.264

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Because the video at `vid_url` is encoded as h264.

Comment: @szatmary Is there any way to transcode the video as it is being downloaded, or would I have to download the whole video first and then transcode it?

Comment: It depends on the videos format.